# Sous le pont Mirabeau

Tags: grammaire, poésie

Dans les vers suivants:

> Passent les jours et passent les semaines
> Ni temps passé
> Ni les amours reviennent
> Sous le pont Mirabeau coule la Seine

("[Le pont Mirabeau](https://writing.upenn.edu/library/Apollinaire_Mirabeau.html)", Apollinaire, Alcools, 1913)

J'ai toujours trouvé que les deux vers du milieu étaient un peu "cassés". N'aurait-il pas été plus correct d'écrire: *Ni **le** temps passé / Ni les amours **ne** reviennent*? Evidemment, les vers n'auraient plus le nombre de pieds requis. Est-ce là la seule raison pour laquelle Apollinaire a écrit ces vers ainsi?

Comment: Tu l'as lu en calligrammes, pardon  je trouve difficile à ajouter moi-même mais en tout cas ça fait partie : https://images.app.goo.gl/Dd5aqB79yAkin7s56

Comment: @livresque Apollinaire lui-même l'a-t'il publié sous la forme d'un calligramme? Je ne l'ai pas trouvé dans son ouvrage _Calligrammes, Poémes de la paix et de la guerre_.

Comment: Peut-être rétrograde ?  T'as raison, peut-être je pensais à Lettre-Océan.

Comment: Rétrograde? Tu veux dire _à titre posthume_?

Comment: Je postule, c'est tout, je veux bien clarifier que ce n'est pas dans *Calligrammes* par Apollinaire, sinon c'est sois posthume sois récrit en honneur.  À la recherche sans fin ( :

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En ce qui concerne la suppression des mots « le » et « ne » voici l'explication de Romain Boussot, professeur de français, auteur de [Mediaclasse](https://www.youtube.com/@mediaclasse), et qui a fait une [analyse détaillée](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTL89MnLKzc) de tout le poème. Romain Boussot inscrit cette strophe dans la persistance des souvenirs et l'analyse ainsi :

> Le temps s’allonge, les « jours » deviennent des « semaines », le verbe « passer » est repris, répété, au point même qu’on peut se demander si le mot « passé » est un adjectif ou un participe passé. L’allitération en S laisse entendre ce passage du temps. Il manque des mots « ni le temps passé, ni les amours ne reviennent » comme en Ancien français où justement les articles et les adverbes sont parfois supprimés. Cela donne une tournure vieillie à ces vers. Le poète joue avec ce qui passe et ce qui perdure.

---

Quelques remarques supplémentaires en réaction aux commentaires sous la question.

- *Le pont Mirabeau* a été publié pour la première fois en 1912 et intégré au recueil [« Alcools »](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcools_(Apollinaire)) l'année suivante.
- La disposition des lignes des éditions sérieuses<sup>1</sup> de nos jours est celle qu'on peut voir dans la vidéo de Romain Boussot (11:04). Sur Gallica on peut voir un [manuscrit](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b525056707/f33.item) de la main d'Apollinaire ainsi que la [toute première publication](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k1050286r/f32.item) du poème en 1912 dans la revue « Les Soirées de Paris ». On constate que dans cette première version la disposition des lignes est différente et que la ponctuation a disparu. C'est Apollinaire lui-même qui a fait disparaître la ponctuation<sup>2</sup>.
- Le poème a été écrit après la rupture avec [Marie Laurencin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marie_Laurencin) en 1912 et avec laquelle il avait eu une liaison pendant six ans. Ils avaient souvent franchi ce pont ensemble.  Apollinaire dira de ce poème qu'il est comme « la chanson triste de cette longue liaison brisée<sup>2</sup> ».

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Toute publication sous forme de calligramme est à mon avis une opération commerciale qui ne correspond pas aux intentions de l'auteur.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> cf [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Pont_Mirabeau).</sup>

Comment: C'est plausible, mais pour des lecteurs qui ne sont pas familiers avec l'Ancien Français, l'effet est un peu raté.